# BioPython phylo: collapsing nodes on tree if node in list and rename the respective collapsed node

Tags: biopython, phylogeny

I have a phylogenetic tree in Newick format, and I would like to remove all species from it that are on a specific list and rename it accordingly.

This is the tree:

```
((((A:0.1, B:0.2):0.3, C:0.3):0.15, (D:0.3, (E:0.1, (F:0.15, (G:0.1, H:0.1):0.1):0.1):0.1):0.1):0.15, I:0.2);
```

This is the table to rename:

```
| species | clade_renaming |
|------------|----------------|
| A, B       | X              |
| F, G, H    | Y              |
```

---

Expected result:

```
(((X:0.3, C:0.3):0.15, (D:0.3, (E:0.1, Y:0.1):0.1):0.1):0.15, I:0.2);
```

---

This is the current code that can collapse nodes:

```
from Bio import Phylo
import io

tree_structure = "((((A:0.1, B:0.2):0.3, C:0.3):0.15, (D:0.3, (E:0.1, (F:0.15, (G:0.1, H:0.1):0.1):0.1):0.1):0.1):0.15, I:0.2);"
tree = Phylo.read(io.StringIO(tree_structure), 'newick')

nodes_to_collapse = ["A", "B", "F", "G", "H"]

def collapse_nodes(tree, nodes_to_collapse):
    for node in tree.find_elements(target=lambda x: x.name in nodes_to_collapse, order="postorder"):
        tree.collapse(node)

collapse_nodes(tree, nodes_to_collapse)
Phylo.draw(tree)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a function to collapse nodes and remove their direct children based on the renaming table. Within this function, I iterated through the rename table, identified the common ancestor for each group of species to be renamed, updated its name, and removed its direct children.

```
from Bio import Phylo
import io

tree_structure = "((((A:0.1, B:0.2):0.3, C:0.3):0.15, (D:0.3, (E:0.1, (F:0.15, (G:0.1, H:0.1):0.1):0.1):0.1):0.1):0.15, I:0.2);"
rename_table = {"A, B": "X", "F, G, H": "Y"}

tree = Phylo.read(io.StringIO(tree_structure), 'newick')

# Function to collapse specified nodes and remove their direct children
def collapse_and_remove_children(tree, rename_table):
    for nodes, new_name in rename_table.items():
        # Remove leading and trailing whitespace from node names
        nodes = [node.strip() for node in nodes.split(',')]
        # Find the collapsed node
        collapsed_node = tree.common_ancestor(nodes)
        # Set the name of the collapsed node
        collapsed_node.name = new_name
        # Remove the direct children of the collapsed node
        collapsed_node.clades = []

# Collapse specified nodes and remove their direct children
collapse_and_remove_children(tree, rename_table)

# Draw the tree
Phylo.draw(tree)
```

[image]

Hi, after working around, I found suitable solution below here

```
from Bio import Phylo
import io

# Input tree and table
tree_structure = "((((A:0.1, B:0.2):0.3, C:0.3):0.15, (D:0.3, (E:0.1, (F:0.15, (G:0.1, H:0.1):0.1):0.1):0.1):0.1):0.15, I:0.2);"
rename_table = {"A, B": "X", "F, G, H": "Y"}

# Read the tree
tree = Phylo.read(io.StringIO(tree_structure), 'newick')

# Function to collapse and rename nodes
def collapse_and_rename(tree, rename_table):
    for nodes, new_name in rename_table.items():
        common_ancestor_names = [node.strip() for node in nodes.split(',')]
        common_ancestor = tree.common_ancestor(common_ancestor_names)
        
        # Calculate the total branch length of the collapsed node
        total_branch_length = sum(child.branch_length for child in common_ancestor.clades if child.branch_length is not None)
        
        # Set the new name for the common ancestor node
        common_ancestor.name = new_name
        
        # Adjust branch lengths of children
        for child in common_ancestor.clades:
            if child.branch_length:
                child.branch_length -= total_branch_length
        # Set the branch length of the collapsed node to the sum of its children's branch lengths
        common_ancestor.branch_length = total_branch_length



# Collapse and rename nodes
collapse_and_rename(tree, rename_table)

# Function to collapse nodes and update branch lengths
def collapse_nodes(tree, nodes_to_collapse):
    for node in tree.find_elements(target=lambda x: x.name in nodes_to_collapse, order="postorder"):
        tree.collapse(node)
nodes_to_collapse = ["A", "B", "F", "G", "H"]
# Collapse nodes and update branch lengths
collapse_nodes(tree, nodes_to_collapse)

# Draw the tree
Phylo.draw(tree)
```

[image]